# ubuntu - block internet access to all applications except chosen few

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ufw

I have been looking for a way to block all my applications from accessing the except for 1 or 2 chosen.

I looked into Uncomplicated Firewall (ufw) and its respective Gui (gufw):

[image]

but gufw doesn't seem to have the option to block specific programs from accessing the internet (which windows firewall does with outbound rules).

**QUESTION:** Does anyone know how I might be able to get that done?

Answer (score 0):

Make a new user acct limit its network and run the programs as sudo when you need network. Just of the top of my head. At work so can't really hash out another solution atm

Comment: Thank you for the response! And how might I go about limiting a users network? When I go to **System Settings** > **Network**, the only option I get in **Wired** is on/off. Also, if I were to manage to limit the network somehow, and then I only wanted the **Firefox** browser to run with a connection, how would the command look in the terminal?